# How do I manipulate the positioning of a draggable inside the "out" (of droppable) event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with positioning using jQuery UI draggable (jQuery UI v1.10.3, jQuery v1.10.2).

I want to drag an item into a **droppable** and then the **droppable** will become its parent and the position will be the same as the relative **mouse** position. This works. The problem is the vice versa case. There i want the **draggable** to become the child of the "box_drop" and the position should be the same as the mouse position in **both dimensions**. (On the side I'm doing some resizing, but there is no problem with that). 
The real problem is, that I can't manipulate the positioning of the draggable if I trigger the out event. The draggable just jumps into the top right corner and also ignores the containment.
You can see it in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ev3nkq1/10/

Main Code is below.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="experimentalbox">
  <div id="box_drop">
    <div class="droppable"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    <span class="draggable"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#experimentalbox{
  position: relative;
}

#box_drop{
  width: 100%;
  height: 61.5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.droppable{
  width: 35%;
  height: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17.5%;
  left: 30%;
}

#box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 23%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15.4%;    
  display: inline-block;
}

.draggable{
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  top: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
  containment: "#experimentalbox",
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui){
    ui.draggable.css({
        "width": parseFloat($("#box").outerWidth() / $(this).outerWidth()) * 10 + "%",
        "height": parseFloat($("#box").outerHeight() / $(this).outerHeight()) * 40 + "%",
    });

    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo(this);
    ui.draggable.css("left", event.pageX - ui.draggable.parent().offset().left - ui.draggable.width()/2);

    var top_draggable_mitte = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() - ui.draggable.outerHeight();
    ui.draggable.offset({top: top_draggable_mitte});
  },
  out: function(event, ui){
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($("#box_drop"));
    ui.draggable.css({
      "width":  parseFloat($("#box").outerWidth() / ui.draggable.parent().outerWidth()) * 10 + "%",
      "height": parseFloat($("#box").outerHeight() / ui.draggable.parent().outerHeight()) * 40 + "%",
    });

    ui.draggable.css({"left": "100%"});
  },
});
```

I'm really looking forward to your replies!

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes
Eric

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your `out` callback is not clear, I don't understand the logic behind it. If you review, you will see *Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events.* There is no object to effect; it would need to be done in Draggable. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-out

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't notice that Note, but I'm wondering why I can change the width and the height of the draggable with ui.
My current work-around is, that you destroy the draggable function, then you replace the draggable and add the draggable function again. The problem here is, that you need to press the mouse button again to drag the object again.